# How to do a multi query using FQL

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ipad, facebook-fql, multi-query

I have a problem fetching data from Facebook using FQL. I currently wanted to fetch albums from the Facebook with cover image url. In order to fetch the cover image, I have to make a query to fetch the albums then using the albums id to fetch the cover image. Since i need both albums' title and the cover image.

I can execute single FQL query using requestWithGraphPath to get the list of albums. But have no idea of how to do multi query.

This is the way I fetch  albums with only single query

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"fql?q=SELECT+aid,name+FROM+album+WHERE+owner+=+me()" andDelegate:albums];

I have a problem doing multi query ... I have looked at other stack overflow and found this:

```
FacebookAlbumCollection* albums = [[FacebookAlbumCollection alloc] init: self];

    NSString* fql1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"select aid,cover_pid,name from album where owner = me()"];
    NSString* fql2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"select pid from photo where pid in (select cover_pid from #albums)"];
    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"{\"albums\":\"%@\",\"photos\":\"%@\"}",fql1,fql2];

   NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"q"];


  [facebook requestWithMethodName:@"fql.multiquery" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:albums];
```

Does anyone know how to do a multi query?

Comment: Im working on this right now, did you manage to get it ?